# Rabbitvcs not working with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rabbitvcs

I have followed all the steps to install from following urls:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/08/install-rabbitvcs-ubuntu-linux-mint-ppa/

http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-rabbitvcs-on-ubuntu-13-04-12-10-12-04-linux-mint-15-14-13-and-elementary-os-0-2-luna/

http://tutorialforlinux.blogspot.in/2013/08/tutorial-install-rabbitvcs-in-ubuntu.html

https://askubuntu.com/questions/167431/just-installed-rabbitvcs-but-nothing-changed-in-nautilus

None is working for me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, better suited for http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Done. http://askubuntu.com/questions/507949/rabbitvcs-not-working-with-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: (I think this can be closed as "unclear", since there is no definitive statement of a configuration that needs fixing).